# Regex to match punctuation followed by space with some exceptions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex which matches punctuation (!, ?, and .) followed by a space. I want to NOT match periods which are preceded by salutations like "Mr.", "Mrs.", etc...

Doing the first part is simple enough:
`r"[\?|!|\.] "`

But I am struggling with the second part. Here is what I have so far:
`r"(?<=[^(Mr|Ms)])\. "`

The second one does NOT match something like "radar. " or "cups. " or "loom. " which is bad. I am also having trouble combining both those regexes into a single one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<!(Mr)|(Ms))(?<!(Mrs))[.!?](?=\s|$)
```

Here's a demo:

```
In [19]: re.search(r'(?<!(Mr)|(Ms))(?<!(Mrs))[.](?=\s|$))', 'Mrs. Jones!').group(0)
Out[19]: '!'
```

There's a negative lookbehind for Mr and Mrs, and a positive lookahead for either a space or EOL.

Please note that each separate salutation of different length will needs its own lookbehind.

---

Edited, as per OP's request:

```
In [78]: re.search(r'((?<!(Mr)|(Ms))(?<!(Mrs))[.])|([!?])(?=\s|$)', 'Mrs! Jones').group(0)
Out[78]: '!'
```

Comment: How would you modify this so that the salutation exceptions only happen before the period? I'd still like to match if a salutation occurs before a "!" or "?". Sorry if I was not clear originally.

Comment: @deruse Edited. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working one: https://regex101.com/r/iRNTMY/2

```
(?<!(Mr|Ms))(?<!(Mrs))[.?!]
```

It uses negative look-behind twice for the two different length possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If want to be complete, you would need to exclude `Prof, Dr, Miss, Mrs, Ms, Mr` etc.

Python's `re` module does not allow for anything other than fixed width lookbacks; therefor, you would need to do multiple lookbacks for each width:

```
r'(?<!\bMr|\bDr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!\bProf|\bMiss)([.,;])(?= |\n|\Z)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/doAQ2y/1/)

Or use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) that would allow variable width lookback assertions. Then you can do:

```
r'(?<!\bMr|\bMrs|\bDr|\bMiss|\bProf)([.,;])(?= |\n|\z)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b2jKsb/3/)

---

Side note: Anything inside a character class matches a *single character*. That is why you get unexpected results with `[^(Mr|Ms)]` That is negated character class for the **individual** characters of the set `Mrs|()`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/issbW0/2/)